# How to delete a GitHub commit which isn't a pull request yet?

Tags: github-issues

I was about to submit a commit, but just before creating a pull request I decided it wasn't needed after all. How do I delete it now?

[image: A GitHub commit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it creates a branch, meaning it can be solved with [GitHub's Deleting a branch](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository#deleting-a-branch).